# check_and_cast() error in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm simulating network in Omnet++, with INET framework. I want to get the position (coordination x & y) of node. So I do this code:

```
    cModule *host = getContainingNode(this);
    IMobility *mobility = check_and_cast<IMobility *>(host->getSubmodule("mobility"));
    ... = mobility -> getCurrentPosition();
```

But, when I ran the simulation, I got this error

> check_and_cast(): cannot cast nullptr to type 'inet::IMobility *'

Can you explain to me this error?
As I see, if the simulator notify that, so ***host->getSubmodule("mobility")*** is nullptr?

By the way, I have define **mobilityType** in the NED file and include **IMobility.h**

Comment: It seems that there is no `mobility` submodule in your host. Could you show ned file of your host?

Comment: @JerzyD.
Here is my host in ned file:


`simple Txc like IMobility`
`{`
    `parameters:`
        `bool isSource = default(false);`
        `bool isDest = default(false);`
        `string mobilityType = default("StationaryMobility");`
        `@display("i=device/hub_vs");`
        `@networkNode;`
    `gates:`
        `inout gate[];`
`}`

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to add code or picture or file in comment

Comment: @JerzyD. I think that error occurred because the type of host **Txc** is simple, so it don't have `Submodule`. But `IMobility` is an interface module, it has no gate

Answer (score 2):

The NED code you shared shows that you have a simple module that implements the IMobility interface, while the C++ code looks like something that is inside a simple module which is INSIDE a compound module that represent the network host and this compound module also contains a separate simple module called "mobility" that implements the IMobility interface. (this is how code is implemented in INET).

You should either:

- arrange your code so you have a compound module as a networkNode with several simple modules inside it (one of them is the mobility module).
- if you insist having a simple module which already implements the IMobility interface (in C++) then you already have access to the position on that object using the `getCurrentPosition` method.

I assume (and recommend) that you co on the first route, so you should reaarange your NED file.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Rudi. I rearrange my host to compound module. The error is fixed. Now I have 2 another questions:
1. I'm confused by the gate in submodules. Can I send message direct to another host without transmit between submodules's gates?

Comment: I wonder if a submodule can act properly without gates? (For example, I add interface module Mobility into my host, but it seems like don't have gate)
And the second problem I want to ask is: Which function I can use to send message broadcast to neighbor of a wireless node? I going to simulate wireless sensor network, can I only use node ID to send message, without IP address (it seems to reduce the information and complexity a node must to store, I don't have to use RoutingTable & IPv4NetworkConfigurator module)?